# Как я могу объединять две спаренные кучи в одну , на языке C ? (Pairing heap)

Tags: c

Мне нужна функция как я могу объединять две спаренные кучи в одну на языке Си. (Pairing heap)

Comment: проходитесь циклом по одной куче, берете по элементу и добавляете в другую кучу и делаете heapify

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: а можно реализацию на си?

Comment: @KoVadim Это особые кучи, их объединение за O(1) [делается](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap#meld)